# What does SQL Server use to do a count(*) on a table?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, heap

Internally, how does SQL Server determine the result for a `select(*)`?  Is it different between a heap and a clustered index?  Is it able to do smart things with the clustered index to not have to load the whole table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a trivial `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable;` query on a disk-based table, SQL server counts rows by scanning either the heap or leaf nodes of an index. The cost-based SQL Server optimizer chooses the narrowest one available in order to minimize the number of pages scanned.

This example shows the behavior with an [index scan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkNmcGvfB).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(
      Column1 int NOT NULL
    );
--load 10K rows
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t1g AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b CROSS JOIN t1k AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable WITH (TABLOCKX) (Column1) 
SELECT num
FROM t1g
WHERE num <= 10000;
GO
CREATE INDEX ncidx_YourTable_IntColumn ON dbo.YourTable(Column1);
GO
--index scan
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
--show heap and index size
SELECT
    i.name              AS IndexName,
    SUM(page_count * 8) AS IndexSizeKB
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
    db_id(), object_id('dbo.YourTable'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS s
JOIN sys.indexes AS i
ON s.object_id = i.object_id AND s.index_id = i.index_id
GROUP BY i.name
ORDER BY i.name;
```

Index/heap sizes:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+
|         IndexName         | IndexSizeKB |
+---------------------------+-------------+
| NULL                      |         272 |
| ncidx_YourTable_IntColumn |         192 |
+---------------------------+-------------+
```

If we fragment the index, it becomes larger than the heap so [the heap is scanned](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkwu9MPGH) instead of the index:

```
--fragment index and update stats
UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET Column1 = 2;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.YourTable;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
--heap scan
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

Heap and index size with fragmentation:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+
|         IndexName         | IndexSizeKB |
+---------------------------+-------------+
| NULL                      |         272 |
| ncidx_YourTable_IntColumn |         648 |
+---------------------------+-------------+
```

After the index is rebuilt, [the index is scanned again](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByQn9MwzB) because it is narrower:

```
--rebuild index
ALTER INDEX ncidx_YourTable_IntColumn ON dbo.YourTable REBUILD;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
--index scan
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

Heap and index size after rebuild:

```
SELECT
    i.name              AS IndexName,
    SUM(page_count * 8) AS IndexSizeKB
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
    db_id(), object_id('dbo.YourTable'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS s
JOIN sys.indexes AS i
ON s.object_id = i.object_id AND s.index_id = i.index_id
GROUP BY i.name
ORDER BY i.name;
GO

+---------------------------+-------------+
|         IndexName         | IndexSizeKB |
+---------------------------+-------------+
| NULL                      |         272 |
| ncidx_YourTable_IntColumn |         192 |
+---------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I will sometimes build a non clustered index on the cluster key for tables that get counted a lot.  Also useful for speeding up foreign key constraint checks if that happens in your environment as well.

Comment: Historical note: prior to SQL 2008; `COUNT(*)` would always scan the table; while `COUNT(1)` could do much much better. Some ancient version of SQL Server used to have this buggy behavior where `COUNT(*)` would count the number of rows that had at least one non-null column; and this bad scan choice was an echo of that buggy behavior.